# Bad results from Tesseract (OCR) in VB.NET

Tags: ocr, tesseract

After trying FreeOCR (which uses the Tesseract engine), I concluded that the OCR-engine from Tesseract fits the quality requirements for a recent project.

However, working with the .NET wrapper for Tesseract-OCR (from https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract), the results are completely different (and extremely bad). Even after copying the tessdata directory from FreeOCR into my project: it doesn't improve.

I noticed that when I use in FreeOCR the OCR => Start OCR Process (in the topmost menu) button for processing, the results are good (like I would want in my VB program too). But when I use OCR => OCR Current Page/OCR All Pages (in the menu with the big buttons below) the results are just as bad as in my VB program. Does it has something to do with this? Is there a way to process an image without using "pages"?

Also I tried to differ in Engine modes, I tried all modes (TesseractOnly, CubeOnly, TesseractAndCube and *default*). Some changes, but both not reasonable at all.

Another thing which I tried is to differ all PageSeg-modes. A lot of difference, but still not as good as it should be.

On internet I found some answers saying: "You have to train your Tesseract", OK, but how? And if the settings from FreeOCR are good enough, how can I just use those?

Also, I know which words will very often (but not only limited to this words) occur in the text. Is it possible to train at least on those words?

I'm just using the following code for my Tesseract process. Maybe this is not right?

```
Dim OCREngine As Tesseract.TesseractEngine = New Tesseract.TesseractEngine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "eng")
Dim OCRImage As Tesseract.Pix = Tesseract.PixConverter.ToPix(TheImg)
Dim Page As Tesseract.Page = OCREngine.Process(OCRImage)
Me.TextBox1.Text = Page.GetText()
```

Thanks in advance